# how to include google slide UI tool for generating slide using google slide api in javascript

Tags: google-slides-api

how to include google slide UI tool for generating slide using google slide api  using javascript. I have read the documentation and services which google slide offers. But do we need to manually create the ui screen for creating and editing the slide or google slide api provide its own ui tool for creation/editing.

Answer (score 0):

The Slides API doesn't provide any UI components-- it's purely a backend API available over HTTP.

If you need your users to modify slides you've created with the API, you can link your users to the Google Slides editor at `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/<presentationId>/edit`.

Comment: can you suggest any other api which provide both UI tool as well as back end api